# Issue updating values in Database from mySQL query on PHP site

Tags: php, mysql, web, phpmyadmin

Been tinkering with my website, it is a seat booking website. Still in alpha testing really so not live to the public yet for obvious reasons.

However, I'm having a few problems with updating the values in my database.

I'll post the code and then explain the problem..

```
     else {

   $seatID = $_POST['form_submitted'];

$query1 = "SELECT seatTaken FROM SEATS WHERE seatNo = '$seatID'";
            $result = mysql_query($query1);  
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
               $taken = $row['seatTaken'];  
            }


$query2 = "SELECT passNo FROM PASSENGER WHERE username = '$loggedinuser'";
            $result = mysql_query($query2);  
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
               $passno = $row['passNo'];  
            }


$query3 = "SELECT groupID FROM PASSENGER WHERE username = '$loggedinuser'";
            $result = mysql_query($query3);  
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
               $groupno = $row['groupID'];  
            }

$query4 = "SELECT flightNo FROM PASSENGER WHERE username = '$loggedinuser'";
            $result = mysql_query($query3);  
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
               $flightno = $row['flightNo'];  
            }


  // if ($taken = 0) {

 $update = mysql_query("UPDATE PASSENGER SET seatNo = $seatID WHERE username = '$loggedinuser'");
 $update2 = mysql_query("UPDATE SEATS SET seatTaken = 1, passNo = '$passNo', groupID = '$groupid' WHERE seatNo = '$seatID'");
 // AND flightNo = '$flightno'"
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.mywebsite.com/">';
       echo mysql_error();

  //}

 }

 ?>
```

Now the user will have selected their seat in the previous form hence the:

```
 $seatID = $_POST['form_submitted'];
```

However, at the bottom in my queries, the only value that actually changes in the database when this PHP code is run is the boolean value of 'seatTaken', in that it does change from 0 (not occupied) to 1 (occupied).

The field passNo and groupID in my database DO NOT UPDATE as referenced here in these queries:-

```
 $update = mysql_query("UPDATE PASSENGER SET seatNo = $seatID WHERE username =     '$loggedinuser'");
 $update2 = mysql_query("UPDATE SEATS SET seatTaken = 1, passNo = '$passNo', groupID = '$groupid' WHERE seatNo = '$seatID'");
```

Is anyone able to help? Many thanks!

Tom

Comment: Where you run an `UPDATE`, print out the query and `exit()`. To debug, run against your database manually and see why it isn't running. Incorrect `WHERE` clauses, possibly?

Comment: You may know about this, but you also have a SQL injection vulnerability in this code. Use parameter binding, or at least escape your tainted inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch your variable naming and string quotation

When your looking for values in mysql, they usually need to be a string literal (add quotes).
And your other problem is your variable names:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE PASSENGER SET seatNo = '$seatID' WHERE username = '$loggedinuser'");
$update2 = mysql_query("UPDATE SEATS SET seatTaken = 1, passNo = '$passno', groupID = '$groupno' WHERE seatNo = '$seatID'");
```

- $passno vs $passNo
- $groupid vs $groupno

You should also make sure you properly escape any input coming from the user http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

One can't see in your code how do you generate the values of $groupid, $passNo, $seatID. Are those varaibles set when you do your update? (just echo the SQL code to see what query is being sent to your database)

Maybe you should try getting the variables from your post request, like $_POST['groupid'], if groupid is the name of the field in the form.